# Sum date and time and find date difference

Tags: php

I have two variables (first is of type **date** and second is of type **time**):

```
$ref_date = '2016-12-22';
$ref_time = '09:00';
```

I need to sum these two and find the date difference from **now - summed_variable**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you read this? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: `$sum = $ref_date . " " . $ref_time;` ? Is that it?

Comment: Its simply needs your effort : https://eval.in/692382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the PHP DateTime object you can do this quite easily

```
$ref_date = '2016-12-22';
$ref_time = '09:00';

$ref = new DateTime($ref_date . ' ' . $ref_time);
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $now->diff($ref);

echo $diff->format('%R%a days %H Hours %i Minutes');
```

And the result would be

```
+14 days 22 Hours 30 Minutes
```